# How to create inherited object using GlobalContainer (Spring4D framework) in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, inheritance, spring4d

I have a problem in creating custom class object inherited from another using GlobalContainer of Spring4D Framework.

Parent class:

```
type
  TVSPSection = class ( TInterfacedObject, IVSPSection )

  private
        _id : Integer;
        _organization : IDirectoryObject;

        function GetId () : Integer;
        procedure SetId ( const value : Integer );
        function GetOrganization () : IDirectoryObject;
        procedure SetOrganization ( const value : IDirectoryObject );

  public
        property Id : Integer read GetId write SetId;
        property Organization : IDirectoryObject read GetOrganization write SetOrganization;

end;

...

initialization

  GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TVSPSection>.Implements<IVSPSection>.
        InjectField ( '_organization' )
        ;
```

Descendant class:

```
type
  TVSPSeismicSection = class ( TVSPSection, IVSPSeismicSection, IInterface )

  private
        _report : IReport;

        function GetReport () : IReport;
        procedure SetReport ( const value : IReport );

  public
        property Report : IReport read GetReport write SetReport;

end;

...

initialization

  GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TVSPSeismicSection>.Implements<IVSPSeismicSection>.
        InjectField ( '_report' )
        ;

end.
```

And my attempt to create object of TVSPSeismicSection:

```
_seismicSection : IVSPSeismicSection;
_seismicSection := GlobalContainer.Resolve<IVSPSeismicSection>;
```

Next, I try to access to 'Organization' field (of parent class) and get access violation error.

```
 _seismicSection.Organization.Id := -1;    <- exception is here
```

So, the question is how to tell parent class to initiate it fields using GlobalContainer resolver? Maybe via DelegateTo method, but how?

One way I have found is to initiate parent fields in descendant class's constructor like this:

```
constructor TVSPSeismicSection.Create ();
begin

  Organization := GlobalContainer.Resolve<IDirectoryObject>;

end;
```

But this violates the Dependency Injection paradigm, because I have to include additional classes (IDirectoryObject) to descendant class.

Comment: Try using the [Inject] attribute on the _organization field instead of calling .InjectField (You'll need to add Spring.Container.Common to your uses clause).  Otherwise show the basic construct of your interfaces.  It works fine for me using the [inject] attribute but not the _InjectField as you used

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Yes, [inject] attribute is nice feature, and I have try it many times but it doesn't work for me. I don't know why, but if I use this attribute I have an access violation error at fields with this attribute. That is why I have used .InjectField.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways and it depends which is the best.
Usually dependencies that are required should be passed as constructor arguments and those that are optional should be passed by property injection.

So if you add a constructor taking an `IDirectoryObject` argument to your `TVSPSection` class the container is able to satisfy that argument if it knows how to resolve `IDirectoryObject`.

That is usually the cleanest way as one rule about using a DI container is to write your code still DI container agnostic and use the container just as a tool but not as a dependency.

If you want to keep property injection then using the `Inject` attribute on that property should work (don't forget to add `Spring.Container.Common` to the uses for that attribute) just as specifying InjectProperty in the registration (while possible I would avoid field injection as that is only doable by RTTI and not regular code - see the previous paragraph).

Comment: Dear Stefan, thanks for the answer. Yes, Inject attribute is now works perfectly (I forgot about Spring.Container.Common).

Comment: Stefan, I would also ask you about a case when object constructor has some parameters and also some implementations. How to simultaneously choose implementation and pass parameters? For example, `GlobalContainer.Resolve<IInterpretationProjectHelper> ( [session] );` where `session` is parametr. So, how to choose required implementation?

Comment: I don't understand that question. And I guess that should not be discussed in comments. Ask a new question or turn to the Spring4D group (you find the link on our project page)